# SQL Top clause with order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am bit new to SQL, I want to write query with TOP clause and order by clause.

So, for returning all the records I write below query

```sql
select PatientName,PlanDate as Date,* from    OPLMLA21..Exams  order
by PlanDate desc
```

And I need top few elements from same query, so I modified the query to

```sql
select top(5) PatientName,PlanDate as Date,* from    OPLMLA21..Exams 
order by PlanDate desc
```

In my understanding it will give the top 5 results from the previous query, but I see ambiguity there. I have attached the screen shot of query results .

May be my understanding is wrong, I read a lot but not able to understand this please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Whhat are *really* using SQL Server or MySQL? Also are you *really* using Compact Edition? CE has been deprecated since 2013!

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: Then tag accordingly, don't tag spam.

Comment: Sorry , i thought concept will be same , i will remove

Comment: `TOP (5)` doesn't give the "top results" of the prior query though, no. It gives the top (first) rows from the dataset defined in the query it in is. If there are multiple rows that have the same "rank", then the row(s) returned for that rank are arbitrary. So, for example, for your query if you have 100 rows all with the same value for `PlanDate`, what 5 rows you get are completely arbitrary and could be different (including the order they are in) every time you run said query.

Comment: The reason why errors like these are hard to spot is because the compiler can choose the same non-parallel query plan every time, and will always return the same result, except for that one time when it doesn't. So the developer has a *perception* that the query is correct, but it is not. When you need data ordered in a specific order, make sure to add the correct `ORDER BY` columns. If you need to guarantee deterministic results between runs, add a unique column to the ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stated this in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348402/sql-top-clause-with-order-by-clause?noredirect=1#comment117298400_66348402), however, to repeat that:

> `TOP (5)` doesn't give the "top results" of the prior query though, no. It gives the top (first) rows from the dataset defined in the query it in is. If there are multiple rows that have the same "rank", then the row(s) returned for that rank are arbitrary. So, for example, for your query if you have 100 rows all with the same value for `PlanDate`, what 5 rows you get are completely arbitrary and could be different (including the order they are in) every time you run said query.

What I mean by arbitrary is that, effectively, SQL Server is free to choose whatever rows, of those applicable, are returned. *Sometimes* this might be the same everytime you run the query, but this by luck more than anything. As your database gets larger, you have more users querying the data, you involve joins, things like locks, indexes, parrallelism, etc all will effect the "order" that SQL Server is processing said data, and **will** effect an ambigious `TOP` clause.

Take the example data below:

```
ID | SomeDate
---|---------
1  |2020-01-01
2  |2020-01-01
3  |2020-01-01
4  |2020-01-01
5  |2020-01-01
6  |2020-01-02
```

Now, what would you expect if I ran a `TOP (2)` against that table with an `ORDER BY` clause of `SomeDate DESC`. Well, certainly, you'd expect the "last" row (with an `ID` of `6`) to be returned, but what about the next row? The other 5 rows all have the same value for `SomeDate`. Perhaps, because your under the impression that data in a table is pre-sorted, you might expect the row with a value of `5` for `ID`. What if I told you that there was a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on `ID ASC`; that might well end up meaning that the row with a value of `1` is returned. What if there is also an index on `SomeDate DESC`?

What if the table was 10,000 of rows in size, and you also have a `JOIN` to another table, which also has a `CLUSTERED INDEX`, and some user is performing a query with some specific row locking on in while you run your query? What would you expect then?

Without your `ORDER BY` being specific enough to ensure that each row has a distinct ordering position, SQL Server will return other rows in an arbitrary order and when mixed with a `TOP` means the "top" rows will also be arbitrary.

*Side note: I note in your image (of what appears to be SSMS), your "dates" are in the format `yyyyMMdd`. This **strongly** implies that you are storing a date value as a `varchar` or `int` type. This is a design flaw and* needs *to be fixed. There are 6 date and time data types, and 5 of them are far superior to using a string and numerical data type to storing the data.*